# deleting repetitive columns in unix

Tags: unix, sed, cut

I would like to delete multiple repetitive columns from a huge file (about 1 million).
The columns that I want to delete has the same column names: A and others has different unique name. Say:

A B2 A B3

1.1 AA 1.2 AA

2.1 AB 4.3 CT

2.2 AC 6.4 GT

so column headers are A, B2, A, B3,... .
How could I delete the columns named as A's from the data.

Comment: show your efforts

Comment: If it's one huge file, the simplest approach is to look at the first line (e.g. `sed -n `1p` or `head -n 1`, identify the bad columns by eye (in your example 1 and 3), then use `cut` to retrieve the others (e.g. `cut -d ' ' -f 2,4`).

Comment: So, just to be clear, are you trying to **delete duplicate columns** (all repeated occurrences of a column name), or to **delete columns with a certain name**?

Comment: I want to delete columns with a certain name: but like the example dataset there are certain properties of the variables. For example one may try to explore to delete each even (or odd) number of columns say 500.000 times.

Comment: Dear All,  I am sorry I did not have time to try all suggestions. Thank you. I am closing this question by great solution of James Brown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another in awk:

```
$ awk '
NR==1 {
    split($0,a)
    for(i in a)
        if(a[i]=="A")
            delete a[i]
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        printf "%s",(i in a?$i OFS:"")
    printf ORS
}' file
B2 B3 
AA AA 
AB CT 
AC GT
```

Comment: }' file here ' should be deleted: other wise perfectly fine!

Comment: This great awk commands solve the problem. Before I run the code:  I added #!/usr/bin/awk -f to the first line

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question correctly, but here an (GNU) `awk` solution to delete all duplicate columns (keeping only the first occurrence):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

NR==1 {
    seen[$1] = 1
    cols[0] = 1
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        if (!($i in seen)) {
            seen[$i] = 1
            cols[length(cols)] = i
        }
    }
}

{
    for (i=0; i<length(cols); i++)
        printf $(cols[i]) " "
    printf "\n"
}
```

For the first line (`NR==1`), we find all non-duplicate columns (preserving the order), and for all the other lines, we just print out the columns (fields) we selected before (`cols` array holds column/field indexes we wish to keep).

```
$ ./filter.awk file
A B2 B3 
1.1 AA AA 
2.1 AB CT 
2.2 AC GT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -d' ' -f $(head -1 filename|tr ' ' '\n'|awk '{if(!seen[$0]++) print NR}'|paste -s -d ',') filename
```

this will work like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

The question is solved by the James Brown code.

I added

## !/usr/bin/awk -f

to the first line of his code  and correct tiny typo at the end of the code (simply additional -'- deleted).

I am sorry, I did not have time to try all other suggestions

with my best wishes